# Does Netsuite have a RESTful API?

Tags: ios, rest, netsuite

I want to do an iOS app that is integrated with [Netsuite](http://netsuite.com), it should have to be done through a RESTful API but I couldn't find anything clear enough on their site, internet or even by talking to their representatives. Does anyone know if there is any documentation around?
Thanks!

Comment: I do not know of a first-party RESTful API, but I did make an attempt at putting one together.  Take a look at http://wispycoder.blogspot.com/2012/04/building-phpsuite-while-napping-pt-1.html hopefully you will find it useful.

Comment: Here is one person's perspective on the question: http://benjsicam.me/blog/netsuite-restlets-commentary-restful-implementation-by-netsuite/ I don't have an opinion until I've had a chance to work with their current restlet implementation which should be real soon now.

Comment: I would recommend using https://github.com/orgs/NetSweet/dashboard to build a standalone endpoint that you can interact with. Distancing your mobile app away from NetSuite using a middleware will enable you to deal with NetSuite's quirks as a separate problem space.

Answer (score 14):

You can interface with NetSuite from a mobile app using one of the SuiteScript types called RESTlets. The documentation is in the [help section](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/PDF/RESTletGuide.pdf) so you will need a login. The [user group community](https://usergroup.netsuite.com/users/index.php) is also active and helpful with RESTlet questions.

Comment: RESTlets do not provide a REST API directly. They only provide the tools and libraries needed for you to build your own REST interfaces.  So to use them you must write a RESTlet and the client code that uses the RESTlet you created.

Comment: @Craig is correct. There are no built in REST API's; they need to be created.

Comment: netsuite's usergroup is pathetic.  Mostly questions and very rarely any netsuite representatives to support.

Comment: That is insane. They have an api, but now everybody has to reimplement the exact same RESTlet layer so they can call it via a REST call? Why not just make the api available directly? This makes no sense. Everybody who wants to load a user record has to implement the exact same javascript restlet that loads a user record and returns the result. There is no stock implementation of this?

Comment: Check out https://github.com/NetSweet/ Some great tools that myself and some other members of the community have been working on to make interacting with NetSuite via SOAP much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I am using an API for my NetSuite integrated app, provided by Halosys (http://halosys.com/new-video-mobile-apps-for-netsuite.html).

The API is integrated with NetSuite and other systems and provides RESTful services for Mobile apps.
More when I launch my Android app but overall happy with the simplified API & notifications etc.

There are a couple more companies that offer similar API service, generally known as a Mobile Backend-as-a-Service but it's important that you look for the ones that are focused on Enterprise and not consumer apps.

HackMobile