# How to integrate Netsuite in ios

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, netsuite

I am using RESTlet script which is given in Netsuite help center and follow same procedure as describe by them. I have login credentials and also able to upload JS file to Netsuite File cabinet but I don't know how to pass GET or POST method for Netsuite.Please provide me sample code for this to create GET and POST method in JS and how to call them. Can anyone help me out to solve out this problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there anyone to overcome here....?

Comment: Please help me about this problem.I will be very thankful to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I have done this. I have user restlets API of netsuite which are described in netsuite help section. I have made some some javascript file and upload them to netsuite server and it works great for me.

Answer (score 2):

Currently the restlets are not accessable via client side JS scripting.  We've spent many hours on this with no ability to connect.  You will have to use a server-side script to accomplish this or an externally available suitelet.

Comment: ok. But whats about what they said in this link      (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867589/does-netsuite-have-a-restful-api)

Comment: Please help me what should i have to do.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to ad NETSUITE sucks as bad as Magento in terms of community support. There seem to be few NetSuite experts who share their ideas online and zilch useful code to get a beginner started.

I have a similar problem looking to post data from a website form to a restlet or suitelet and a complete DIY with working code is nowhere to be found. What gives with this community? The company is pathetic in providing answers. They just point you to the user manual and say "good luck"!

Answer (score 1):

I've done a bunch of large scale NetSuite integration projects and I would recommend NOT using NetSuite's RESTlets as an API to NetSuite.

The best method I've found to integrate with NetSuite is to use their SOAP API using the `netsuite` and `netsuite_rails` ruby gems. Create a rails/sinatra app that sits in between your iOS app and NetSuite and handle all of the NetSuite complexity in the Rails/Sinatra application instead of in a Suitelet or your iOS application.

The development tools for developing Suitelets are very poor and it'll end up taking longer to develop, debug, and maintain your NetSuite integration via Suitelets than creating a separate application that acts as a simplified interface to NetSuite (it'll also allow you to write unit tests for your business logic fairly easily).

Answer (score 0):

You need to have knowledge on Suitescript API. From there you can build your own REST using Netsuite Restlets (No built-in restful service, you have to create it yourself). All you need is the URL from the created Restlet so you can consume it in the any application, as long as the credentials needed are set in the header correctly.